# jquery - element id found after debug alert

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I'm trying to understand what jquery is doing but having no luck. 
When I have the following code for a select box it is not picked up or not id is not found to get picked up by multiselect:

```
 $("#eventplatform").multiselect({
    header: false,
    noneSelectedText: "Domains",
    selectedList: 4 // 0-based index
    });
```

However ...
when I have this line above the code:
    `alert($('#eventplatform').attr('id'));`
everything works as soon as i close the alert.

any ideas would be great - thanks.

Comment: Is your code inside the .ready() handler?  https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: it is yes:     `$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.ost_events').click(function () {
...
                $.get("/tpl/dialog/addevent_dialog.tpl", function(data){
           alert($('#eventplatform').attr('id'));
                $("#eventplatform").multiselect({
                                header: false,
                                noneSelectedText: "Domains",
                                selectedList: 4 // 0-based index
                               });

                $(".pad_block").show();
                });

});`

Answer (score 0):

The reason why adding alert() works is because at the time you click ok, the document will be finished rendering. Just make sure you put it inside a $(document).ready

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#eventplatform").multiselect({
    header: false,
    noneSelectedText: "Domains",
    selectedList: 4 // 0-based index
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry for lack of information in the first place - it already is inside the block. Here is the full code:

Comment: where is your full code? try put it on fiddler or plunkr

Answer (score 0):

i managed to get it working - as mentioned it was something to do with document not ready - here is what was added:

```
` $.get("/tpl/dialog/addevent_dialog.tpl", function(data){

                     $('body').append(data).delegate('#ifclose', 'click', function(){
                            $('.pad_block_page_1').fadeOut(function() {
                                    $(this).remove();
                                    });
                            });
                    $(function () {
                            $("#eventplatform").multiselect({
                                    header: false,
                                    noneSelectedText: "Domains",
                                    selectedList: 4 // 0-based index
                                    });
                            });

                    });`
```